# Is there a way to make a Go app with a Makefile to be "go gettable"?

Tags: go, makefile, go-get

I have a few projects in Go that contain a Makefile to perform various tasks to build, install, create assets, run generators etc. Is there a way to make such programs "go gettable", or I have to figure out a way to substitute Makefile with something else?

Comment: Sure: commit the generated things, so there's nothing to be done anymore except compiling.

Comment: There is nothing else to substitute it with. `go get` just runs `go install`, which just runs `go build`. If your app does not build properly by `git clone;go build`, it is not "go gettable".

Comment: Good point @Peter, thanks